# Disable automatic plugin update

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

We developed plugins for Eclipse Neon which extend some of the Eclipse CDT plugins Some of these plugins are patched (patches mostly include changes of method modifiers) so we can extend their functionality.

Problem comes when user has CDT repository site in their Eclipse. Then when new CDT version comes out, Eclipse offers updates to these users. If they accept it the update will override our patches and our plugins will be broken.

Is there any way (workaround) to disable some plugin site(s) via our plugin?

Comment: What are you extending that breaks on a new release? Official APIs don't break like this.

Comment: Hello, thank  you for your reply. As I said, we have patches in CDT. For example in file CVariable.java in package org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.c we needed acces to attributes so we changed their modifiers from private to protected etc (extension point org.eclipse.cdt.core.language). After update these attributes will be probably private again, also (in case of model redesign) they could be removed or so (since they do not belong into public API).

Comment: So you are breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). You will have to tell people this and tell them they can't update.

Comment: Yes. we do. Yes I know that that is the "right way". But still workaround which disables CDT repository when our plugin is present would work better and would cause much less confusion for people who will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue using feature patch and dependency on CDT. For inspiration you can look on [Groovy Eclipse](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki) project, which solves same problem with JDT.

Answer (score 0):

`Window > Preferences > Install/Update` From there you can either disable the CDT repository, or configure the general update strategy of Eclipse IDE.

However, as other mentioned in comments, the root cause of your issue seems to be some bad dependency management. Setting version constraints more accurately according to OSGi Semaantic Versioning and [Eclipse Guidelines](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering) in your plugins should prevent this bad situation from happening.